# DRF: A theoretical approach on the proper use of Serializers and ViewSets

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I love Python and Django, and I've been learning Django REST Framework for the past weeks, because there is no escape to REST today in 2020.
In my hobbie project (which is a Python forum, ridicously called Pyrty because it is a Python Party), I decided to make a CRUD for the `comments` app. I did it (except by update), but I don't get what is the difference between putting the code in the Serializer and/or in the ViewSet.

My `create` and `list` are in the Serializer, while `delete` is in the ViewSet. All of them are working as expected, but I don't want to code dirty and I wish to understand the important points and differences of putting something in one part or the other.

comments.models.py:

```
class Comment(PyrtyModel): # the inheritance class just adds creation and modification dates, and sorting stuff

    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey('posts.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)

    positive_votes = models.ManyToManyField('users.User', related_name='c_positive_vote_set')
    negative_votes = models.ManyToManyField('users.User', related_name='c_negative_vote_set')

    score = 0

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # init with the score (positive votes - negative votes) if the comment is persisted
        super(Comment, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.id is not None:
            self.score = (
                self.positive_votes.all().count() -
                self.negative_votes.all().count()
            )

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the comment str."""
        return "'{}'".format(self.content)

    class Meta(PyrtyModel.Meta):
        ordering = ['created', 'modified']
```

comments.serializers.py:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Comment model serializer."""

    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create a new comment in some post, by request.user."""

        validated_data['user'] = self.context['request'].user
        return super().create(validated_data)

    def list(self, request):
        """List all the comments from some post."""

        if 'post' not in request.query_params:
            raise ValidationError('Post id must be provided.')

        q = self.queryset.filter(post=request.query_params['post'])
        serializer = CommentSerializer(q, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

comments.views.py:

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()

    def get_permissions(self):
        permissions = []
        if self.action == 'create' or self.action == 'destroy':
            permissions.append(IsAuthenticated)
        return [p() for p in permissions]

    def get_object(self):
        """Return comment by primary key."""
        return get_object_or_404(Comment, id=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Delete a comment created by request.user from a post."""

        instance = self.get_object()
        if instance.user != request.user:
            raise ValidationError('Comment does not belong to the authenticated user.')
        self.perform_destroy(instance)
        run_reputation_update(request.user)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        pass
```

Where and when should I put the code in one part or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializers are used to validate the request data (incoming params) and to format (serialize) data to be sent back in response.

Additionally, serializers have methods like `create`, `update` and `save` where you can define the logic of how the validated data should be saved. Especially this is handy for ModelSerilizers.

All other logic should be defined in views/viewsets.

I'm pretty sure that your `list` method in your `CommentSerializer` doesn't do a thing. Cause serializers don't have `list` method, you defined it there but it's never used. `ModelViewSet` on the other hand has `list` method, and I'm pretty sure that's what used when you fetch your comments list, not the `list` method in your serializer.